# Pine Script count sequenze on for

Tags: pine-script

I need a counter inside a for loop to identify if I'm on 1st 2nd or 3rd (i) so to speak
a kind of odd and even, but in this case I also have the 3rd number
so I should check the number sequences
1-4-7 or 2-5-8 or 3-6-9 .... etc .... and then set my variables. THANK YOU

```
count=0 
MyVariable=0
for h = 0 to 10
    if count = 0
        count:=1
        MyVariable := 5
    else if count = 1
        count:=2
        MyVariable := 10            
    else if (count = 3)
        count:=0
        MyVariable := 18
```

I have tried to do this, but as soon as I remove the rems from array.push I get the following error "Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (void; series[integer]; series[integer])"

```
array.sort(PDelta)
plot(array.size(PDelta))    
_valore=""
Count=1
Ptest=array.new_string()
//Scorro i Delta
for j = 0 to (i_size)-1
    _value = array.get(PDelta,j)
    //Scorro tutti
    for h = 0 to (i_size)-1
        //controllo Delta
        if (Count==1)
            Count:=2
            //array.push(Ptest,"Test")
        else if (Count == 2)
            Count:=3
            //array.push(Ptest,"Test")
        else if (Count == 3)
            Count:=1
            //array.push(Ptest,"Test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have another branch in your `if` statement that's returning another type of value. The `if` statement in Pine can be used to assign a value to a variable, as in:

```
v = if ...
```

Because of that, the compiler enforces the type of the values returned in `if` blocks. You can work around it by using this:

```
if (Count==1)
    Count:=2
    array.push(Ptest,"Test")
    int(na)
else if (Count == 2)
    Count:=3
    array.push(Ptest,"Test")
    int(na)
else if (Count == 3)
    Count:=1
    array.push(Ptest,"Test")
    int(na)
else
    Count:=4
    int(na)
```

Comment: Perfect very very THANKS